# how can i select this element in python from bs4

Tags: python, html

```
<time class="FH9sR Nzb55" datetime="2020-04-17T05:27:22.000Z" title="2020-04-17">4일</time>
```

this Html form the under code.

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url=input("url?")
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

time=soup.find('time')
print(time)
```

''''

i want to select "2020-04-17" in title ""

i used BeautifulSoup4 library how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
time = soup.find('time', class_='FH9sR Nzb55').get('title')
print(time)
```